# The javascript positioned elements fall out of place before the javascript is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Within my site, a few elements are positioned using javascript. I also use javascript for setting the `width` and `height` for some other elements.

The problem is that on load, the elements fall out of place for a few seconds, untill the javascript is executed.

As an example:

I want to avoid **this** happen:

[image]

This is how I call my positioning function:

```
$(window).load(function(){


            apply_javascript(); // all positioning stuff is here

        });
```

Any suggestions? 
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `CSS` to position elements?

Comment: @lshettyl Well, I'm using the js to set the height of a container that holds absolute positioned divs - that means they are not inside the normal "flow" so I can't determine they're size

Comment: Hide elements, and show them when page is loaded and positions are calculated (or fade page in, little nicer)

Comment: Sure, in that case, you still can set the positon of those elements via `CSS` and set the height/width via JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously reconsider attempting to do all your positioning with CSS if possible.

In the meantime, perhaps something like:

```
<body>
    <script>
        $("body").hide(); // first thing to happen in the body of your html
    </script>
</body>
```

then in your load script:

```
$(function(){ //equivalent to $(window).load(function...
    $("body").show();
    //...
});
```

Comment: Won't this hurt my SEO? The google bots will crawl my page and for the first seconds will find nothing

Comment: Hmm. There's a lot of conjecture about just how much javascript the googlebot runs. I've used this to no ill-effect on SEO.

Answer (score 1):

What if you put your function in between `<head>` tags and use window.onpaint?

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(window).load(function preloadFunc(){


        apply_javascript(); // all positioning stuff is here

    });
    window.onpaint = preloadFunc();
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Is this safe for seo?

Comment: More to the point, is this safe at all? ["Not working in Gecko-based applications currently, see Notes section!", and "Not part of any standard"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/onpaint)